# cut string from one point to another if there is the presence of another

Tags: java, string

I have the following string and want to cut it after the word `RUN` to the character `&` only if the string contains the word `RUN`

```
portal.sidiv.registrocivil.cl/docstatus?RUN11111111-1&typeCEDULA&serial107172548&mrz29272904762037262937
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String cutString(String target, String pattern) {
    if (target.contains(pattern)) {
        return target.split(pattern)[1].substring(0, target.split(pattern)[1].indexOf('&'));
    }
    return target;
}
```

And test:

```
 public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(cutString("portal.sidiv.registrocivil.cl/docstatus?RUN11111111-1&typeCEDULA&serial107172548&mrz29272904762037262937", "RUN"));
    }
```

returns: 11111111-1

Comment: Thanks! I served a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick code snippet to do it:

```
String str = "portal.sidiv.registrocivil.cl/docstatus?RUN11111111-1&typeCEDULA&serial107172548&mrz29272904762037262937";
String result = str.contains("RUN") ? str.substring(str.indexOf("RUN") + 3,str.indexOf("&")) : null;
if(result != null) {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Output:

```
11111111-1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer friend!